# Quartz scheduler with custom calendar system

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler

Can I use quartz to schedule a job in a custom calendar system? for example fire a job in first day of every jalali (shamsi) month.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can. Implement quartz calendar to make your own.

Or follow this tutorial: http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.x/tutorials/tutorial-lesson-04

Comment: The accepted answer does not provide solution for a custom non gregorian calendar. It only excludes days such as Holidays. I will re-post the question.